# Convergence in the trivial topology

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I am currently trying to understand the terms neighbourhood and convergence. The definitions seems clear to me. I am however stuck seeing why this true:

In the trivial topology any sequence converges to every point (1).

By definition $x_n$ converges to $a$, if **all** neighbourhoods of $a$ contain every, but finitely many elements of $x_n$.

For example: 
Given $X = \{x,y\}, P(X) = \{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\}, \{x, y\}\} $ then $(X, P(X))$ is the trivial topology.

I may then define the constant sequeunce $x_n = x \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Obviously $x_n$ converges to $x$, but apparently also to $y$ (given the topology above), but I don't see why. $y$ has the neighbourhoods $N_1 = \{y\}$ and $N_2 := \{x,y\}$, obviously $x_n$ lies $N_2$, however not in $N_1$. Hence there is an open neighbourhood of $y$, that doesn't contain all but finitely many elements of $x_n$ and thus $x_n$ doesn't look like it converges to $y$.

The concepts are probably all very easy and intuitive, however I don't see where I go wrong and why (1) is in fact true.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the *trivial* topology with the *discrete* topology, which are *very* different: in the trivial topology every sequence converges, because the only nonempty open set is the whole set; in the discrete topology only eventually constant sequences converge.

The trivial topology on $X$ is $\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are misunderstanding the meaning of “[trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology)”. It is the topology for which the (only) open sets are the whole space and the empty set. Given a set $X$, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the *discrete* topology, not the trivial one.

Comment: In fact, to avoid this confusion,  I prefer the name "indiscrete topology". It's clearly the most opposite topology to the discrete one.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That's my opinion, too.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial topology is $\{\emptyset, X\}$. Then obviously $x=x_n\to y$. Indeed, the only neighbourhood of $y$ is $\{x,y\}$ and all terms of the sequence $(x_n)$ belong to it.

The same argument applies to any $X\ne\emptyset$ with a trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$.